# pandas caveats SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I could not resolve the warning from Pandas caveats when I try to replace a column (A) at index no. with another value in column (B) of the same index no. Couldn't find relevant answers to solve this.

```
df['A'].iloc[3] = df['B'].iloc[3]
```

Warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> df['A'].iloc[3] = df['B'].iloc[3]

I don't think `.copy()` is relevant for this within the same dataframe.

Comment: I didn't get any error, which version of pandas you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks, it helps

```
# Copy 2nd row of 2nd column into 2nd row of 1st column
df.iloc[2, [0]] = df.iloc[2, [1]]
```